# Java JDBC Connection using Socks

Tags: java, jdbc, proxy, websphere, socks

Using Java, I need to connect to a SQL Server database using JDBC. I need to go through our companies SOCKS proxy, so I did this and it appeared to work.

```
Connection conn = null;

Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.setProperty("socksProxyHost","socksproxy.domain.com");
systemProperties.setProperty("socksProxyPort","1081");

connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:60304;databaseName=myDatabase;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2;";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"MyLogin","MyPassword");
```

However, I started seeing some odd things.  The code is running in websphere in a JVM with numerous other applications.

After some testing, it appears changing the properties actually affects the entire JVM.  Other connections (LDAP, DB Connections) were also trying to use the SOCKS proxy I defined.

Is there another way of forcing my JDBC connection to go through socks that isn't global?

Comment: the answer to your question depends on what is reading these system properties, and if that code is capable of reading the properties from anywhere else besides `System.getProperty()`

Comment: Of course they affect the entire JVM. That's what they're for. They are read by `java.net.Socket`. @AndyGuibert

Comment: I updated the code block to include the jdbc connection code.  The driver I'm using is mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar.  Is there any way other than system properties to get the jdbc connection to use socks?

Comment: According to the online docks https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

when setting proxy  using the System.setProperty its "all or nothing" meaning it will set the JVM to use all connection according to the property you set.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but I ended up creating a distinct JVM that sets the proxy host and port.  I'll use that JVM for any functionality that needs to connect to an external database.