# Configure JDBC to use SOCKS proxy

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, proxy, socks

I'm trying to access an MS SQL database via JDBC.  My code looks similar to this using the com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver package:

```
SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);
ds.setServerName("{IP Address}");
ds.setPortNumber({Port});
ds.setDatabaseName("{db name}");
```

I need to setup the connection to route through a SOCKS proxy.  I can't and dont' want to set the proxy globally as it has negative impacts to the rest of the system.  I was hoping somthing like ds.setProxy() would exist, but in the absense of such a method I'm not sure how to move forward.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure a SOCKS proxy for a JDBC database connection object?

Comment: JDBC itself doesn't define anything for it, so that would be up to individual drivers, and I can't recall seeing a driver that has this (on the other hand I have never needed it, so I might have overlooked it).

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Java JDBC Connection using Socks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880979/java-jdbc-connection-using-socks)